# Scrolling into another section issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello, I have a problem I tried 3 hours to make a auto scrolling to another section when 25% of bottom section is visible.**

[Section 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpBnJ.png)

[Section 2 after 25% is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1gKN.png)

[Auto scroll to section 2 100% screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTfbg.png)

Sorry I don't have a code for what I do for 3 hours because **nothing working** so I deleted everything :(

That only what I have

```css
  section{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section:nth-child(1){
  color: #e0ffff;
  }
section:nth-child(2){
  color: #42455a;
  background: #e0ffff;
} 
section:nth-child(3){
  color: #e0ffff;
}
section:nth-child(4){
  color: #42455a;
  background: #e0ffff;
}
```

Comment: Its understandable that you gave up on your old code, however to expect help, you must post some code for the community to look at else you will get down votes and the question will be closed as it brings no real value to the community or for your issue. I suggest next time you post to make sure to post some code in your question or edit your current question that at the least outlines your issue.

Comment: Are you using IntersectionObserver?

Comment: Actually I don't have enough experience in javascript to know what's IntersectionObserver but I tried to make some edits in code in another websites to match my site but nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is scroll snap

```
//html
<div id='globalSection'>
<section id='section1'>
</section>
<section id='section2'>
</section>
<section id='section3'>
</section>
</div>

//css
#globalSection{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#globalSection section{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```